# Java (1 != 1) is true

Tags: java

I have an `if` statement in my code as follows:

`if (key != a[0]) /* line to be executed */`

When I run my program with `key = 1` (type Integer) and `a[0] = 1` (type Integer), I get a `true` and the statement runs, i.e. 1 does not equal 1. Obviously, this is absurd.

I've done a lot of testing on this, and I can't find a value of `key` that will give me a `false` for `key != a[0]`. `a[0]` can't change, for the purposes of my program.

What's wrong?

Comment: Try: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7520432/what-is-the-difference-between-vs-equals-in-java

Comment: Every wrapper class types must be compared using the `equals` method only.

Comment: Thanks! My apologies that I couldn't find the answer by myself.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`.equals()` method checks for equality, `==` operator checks for object sameness.  As long as key and a[0] are not the same `Object`, `==` will return false.  `.equals()` on an `Integer` will return true.

Comment: Adding to the answer, `==` does not check for sameness. It checks for the object references. If both operands refer to the same object, it will return true.